# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in Web.api filestream

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data, ioexception, form-data

I have this chunk of code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[Route("api/doc/ImageUpload")]
public HttpResponseMessage ImageUpload()
{
    try
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/imageUpload");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
                }

                string fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
                {
                    fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
                }
                if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
                {
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                }

                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(file.LocalFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
    }  
}
```

And this Postman call:

[image]

I can see the file is being generated in the folder:

[image]

But when trying to actually use the file in file stream and save it as proper jpeg or png I'm getting the IOException. Also I'm noticing the file saved is 32kb but the file I'm trying to upload is 120kb.